# NameError: name 'sent_tokenize' is not defined

Tags: python, nltk

I'm currently using google colab to read a txt file and break it down into sentences by using nltk.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
with open ('demo.txt','r') as file:
  content = file.read()
  print(content)
sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(content)
print(sentences)
```

When I click run,

*****[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!*****
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
1 import nltk
2 nltk.download('punkt')
----> 3 tokenizer= sent_tokenize()
4 sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(content)
5 print(sentences)
NameError: name 'sent_tokenize' is not defined*

This error comes up. By the way, I have already installed nltk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import sent_tokenize

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')
with open ('demo.txt','r') as file:
   content = file.read()
   print(content)
sentences = sent_tokenize(content)
print(sentences
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It says: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ce5f133c0bdc> in <module>()
----> 1 from nltk.tokenize import tokenize
      2 sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(content)
      3 print(sentences)

ImportError: cannot import name 'tokenize' from 'nltk.tokenize' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py)